# The stream or file "...\storage\logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, windows-10

I'm a newbie to laravel. I used xammp and composer to install laravel. The installing process was successful. But when I try to launch localhost:8000 it says

The stream or file "C:\Windows\System32\AwesomeProject\storage\logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in
append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

OS is windows 10. So Please help me to fix this problem...

Comment: As lgflorentino has said in the answering section, this error occured because of system32. It was the problem for permission denied. When I tried to make my project's root folder out of the C partition it fixed this problem. However I'm not gonna delete this question since I tried to find an answer to this problem from the internet but none of the existing answers were worked for me except lgflorentino's one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the directory exists and the permissions on the directory are writable by your user. `C:\Windows\System32` is not the right place for your Laravel project.

Comment: The problem was System32. I think it was the reason for permission denied. When I built my project's root folder out of the C partition the problem was fixed. Thanks for the Hint...